# Загрузил laravel project на хостинг

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте. Помогите, реально, уже не знаю в чем ошибка. Загружал до этого сайты laravel на хост, все работало отлично. Сейчас кидает 500 ошибку, что сайт, "пока-что" не может обрабатывать запросы.
На localhost'e все идеально работает, обрабатывается, загрузил на хост и все. Логи не пишутся кстати.

Comment: В данном случае разберись для начала, как включить логи на своем хостинге. Но чтобы выводить ошибки, в самом начале `public/index.php` пропиши 
`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`
и посмотри на выводимые ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, решение оказалось очень простым, на этом хостинге была ниже версия пхп, и отключены некоторые модули

Comment: используй виртуалки, на них ставь сразу сам все что нужно, и не будет таких проблем))